Help with player strafing rotation
Problem:
Player strafes in all directions fine but when rotated 180 degrees the opposite direction he can barely move in any direction.
//Move the player
_controller.Move(new Vector3(_input.move.x, 0f, _input.move.y) * Time.deltaTime * MoveSpeed / 2);

//Rotate the player according to the camera's x rotation
_controller.gameObject.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, _cinemachineTargetYaw, 0f);

This script is on the starter assets character controller.
have also tried the following with the same effect:
_controller.gameObject.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, Quaternion.Euler(0, _cinemachineTargetYaw, 0), 15f * Time.fixedDeltaTime);

I’m thinking i shouldn’t use the camera as the rotation reference but am stuck on where to go from here
Thanks for any advice or help at all

Is this a top-down view? Over-the-shoulder view? "rotated 180 degrees the opposite direction" from what? The camera? What type of object is _input?

it was over the shoulder. I actually just solved it.

The problem wasn't caused by the rotation. It was actually the move function as what I have above wasn't calculating the move based off of player direction.

If this answer worked for you, remember to click the ✅ icon to the left (after any enforced waiting period) to mark it as "Accepted".
